# How can I see where I am comitting to using team > commit on eclipse using svn / subversive

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

When I right click on a project and select commit it does not show the repository URL of where the commit is going in the commit window, which can be pain for developers.  Is there a way to enable this?

Above the project I can see a path along the lines of `https://repos.domain.com/repos, Trunk:trunk`

Unfortunately this is not always accurate.  For example when I am on a branch called `MyBranch`and select `Team > Branch` it makes the new branch within the `MyBranch` branch folder, instead of creating it within the `branches` folder.  I've made this mistake a few times but by my project it will tell me:

`https://repos.domain.com/repos, Branch:newBranch`

when the path is `https://repos.domain.com/repos/project/branches/MyBranch/NewBranch` instead of `https://repos.domain.com/repos/project/branches/NewBranch`

Is there a way to improve on this level of accuracy?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything more convenient than choosing `Properties` and then `SVN Info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, Subclipse would be a better option.

Here's a screen shot of the Subclipse commit window on Eclipse 3.7.  The Subversion directory is right at the top of the window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Properties > SVN` info.  I didn't about this and was looking for something within the `team` menu.  I'll leave the question open incase there is a way to view the full repository path next to the project.